# How to use nedb api from different modules in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, nedb

I have initialized a database in foo.js and saved some data into it.

```
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var bar = require('./bar.js');

var db = new Datastore({filename: './foo.db', autoload: true});
// saving some data here
db.insert(doc, function (err, newDoc) {}
```

Now I am trying to access the db in bar.js

```
var Datastore = require('nedb');

var db = new Datastore({filename: './foo.db', autoload: true});

// finding data from same store
var bars = db.find({ system: 'solar' }, function (err, docs) {return docs}
```

Now I get this error: `Uncaught Error: ENONET: no such file or directory, rename food.db -> foo.db~`

I understand I can't call NeDB more than once for the same filename.

So how do I access the db and do operation on it on different module like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create file let's call it db.js with bellow code:

```
var Datastore = require('nedb'); 
module.exports = new Datastore({filename: './foo.db', autoload: true});
```

now require this file wherever you want to use it

```
var db = require('./db.js');

db.insert(....);
```